# The Directive on Copyright in the Digital Single Market, also known as EU Copyright Directive and file 2016/0280(COD)

Tags: copyright, internet, european-union

Going to WikiPedia, I have been drawn attention to a new EU directive on Copyright.

## [The Directive on Copyright in the Digital Single Market, also known as EU Copyright Directive and file 2016/0280(COD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_on_Copyright_in_the_Digital_Single_Market)

The image below was displayed at the top when I went to WikiPedia
[image]

> [A] proposed European Union directive with the stated goal to harmonize aspects of copyright law in the Digital Single Market of the European Union. It is an attempt to adjust copyright law for the Internet by providing additional protection to those who own material. The European Parliament Committee on Legal Affairs approved the proposal on June 20, 2018 with further voting by the entire parliament required before it becomes law.
>
> The directive's proposals include giving publishers the ability to request payment for the use of short bits of text, that for-profit websites who primarily host content posted by users must take "effective and proportionate" measures to prevent unauthorized postings of copyrighted content, and copyright exceptions for text and data mining by scientific research institutions

Wikipedia has an article on it called [Directive on Copyright in the Digital Single Market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_on_Copyright_in_the_Digital_Single_Market)

This question also ties in with https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29938/payment-for-content-creators-if-the-copyright-in-the-digital-single-market-direc

A copy of the proposed directive can be found [here at the European Commission Website](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:52016PC0593&from=EN)

**Update:** [the EU has recently approved the Copyright Directive](https://www.theverge.com/2018/9/12/17849868/eu-internet-copyright-reform-article-11-13-approved)

**Further Update** as @danuker pointed out in the comments, the final vote was yesterday (27th March 2019) and the result along with amendments have been detailed at [this Forune.com page](http://fortune.com/2019/03/26/eu-copyright-directive-article-13-passed).

The directive will need to be implemented in EU member countries by 2021 but some member countries may implement the directive much earlier.

As a fair few sites on StackExchange e.g. [Psychology.SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com) quote and link to content from other sites including scientific articles, journals etc., is there a possibility this will affect StackExchange and StackOverflow?

Comment: As far as I can tell the directive is only proposed; is there any information about when it might actually come into effect?

Comment: The final vote was yesterday (2019-03-27).

Comment: Thanks for that @danuker I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @phoog, accordign to the wikipedia article: " In order for the text of the directive to become law in the EU, it must be approved by the European Council (EC) on 9 April 2019." The recent vote was, I gather final in the EP, but not actually final. Or else I have misunderstood

Comment: @DavidSiegel I believe your understanding is correct.  I also note that the Wikipedia sentence misstates the situation described in the article, which is that the directive requires approval from the council and the approval is expected on 9 April, not that the approval must come on 9 April for it to be effective.

Comment: Sorry to come so late to the party, and how is SE a "for-profit" website?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - Take a look at https://www.cbinsights.com/company/stack-exchange-fka-stack-overflow/financials

Comment: Also, @RobbieGoodwin, Co-founder Joel Spolsky said in his blog at https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2019/03/28/the-next-ceo-of-stack-overflow/ that StackExchange made $70 million profit in 2018.

Comment: OMG! Thanks, guys. Excuse my ignorance, and I've never seen anything on SE that looked monetizable… Oops!