# How can I ensure EU citizens can share my content?

Tags: copyright, internet, european-union

I've been hearing things about the new [Article 11 and Article 13 legislation](http://archive.is/5eH1v) which recently passed in the European parliament which regulate the ways that, for example, social media or news aggregation sites can summarize content when displaying links to or aggregating content from other sites.

I am not an EU citizen, and at any rate do not want for these limitations and regulation to apply to my content; I would prefer for something closer to US "fair use" rules apply, or, in many cases, my content is explicitly licensed under open source licenses which explicitly permit free sharing.

Is there some method, automated or otherwise, by which I can opt my content out of this legislation?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the act which passed is a formal *proposal* for a new directive, not the directive itself, so these provisions are not yet effective.  I was not able to find any information suggesting when they might be likely to become effective.

Answer (score 1):

Articles 11 & 13 has created a potentially serious situation which may have implications for StackExchange as I have asked about in [The Directive on Copyright in the Digital Single Market, also known as EU Copyright Directive and file 2016/0280(COD)](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/29952)

For purposes you mention here, you could add a banner on your site, or something similar.  You can word it to suit your needs, but you can state that

> Subject to [fair use rules](http://fairuserules) **[link to your fair use rules site page]** you would not persue anyone under EU articles 11 or 13 if found to be linking to, paraphrasing, or quoting text from your site.  This way you would clearly indicate your wishes.